# How to add text to the end of various digits using sed command?

Tags: html, bash, unix, sed, reference

I am trying to replace `page=#"` in various html files with `page=#/index.html"`. I have tried using the command:

`sed -i -re 's|"(page=[0-9]+)"|"\1/index.html"|' *.html`

along with numerous interpretations but have not been successful. The first part of the code `sed -i -re 's|"(page=[0-9]+)"|` seems to be working properly but I cannot seem to format the end to achieve my goal. Any suggestions to modify this command would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to replace `page=#"` where the actual strings look like `page=99"`, then the first double quote in the RE isn't going to match anything correctly. It would only match if it looks like:

```
"page=99"
```

But I'm guessing this is at the end of a link in html so it probably does not have the initial double quote. This should work instead:

```
`sed -i -re 's|(page=[0-9]+)"|\1/index.html"|' *.html
```

Also to confirm, if you're on OS X, you can't use the GNU option `-r` or use `-i` without an argument, so it would look like this:

```
`sed -i '' -Ee 's|(page=[0-9]+)"|\1/index.html"|' *.html
```

`-E` means to use Extended Regular Expressions so you can write `(` instead of `\(` for grouping. In GNU `sed` this is `-r`.

`-i` means to edit the files in-place, on GNU it can take no argument, but on other systems you need to pass the extension to make for a backup, or `''` for no backup.

Comment: Thank you Adam B, omitting the `"` at the beginning did the trick!

Comment: Great to hear. In this context the string is very literal and the quotes don't act like quotes, just characters.